# Calculate Created_at date which is null in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have few records null in database table and I want to update created_at for those records in table so what I was thinking to do.

| ID | Name | created_at | Scenario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data1 | 20/01/2021 08:00:30 | Exists |
| 2 | Data2 |  | For blank, Will enter this value using migration comparing 1st and 5th row date, and date should be less than 5th row and greater than 1st |
| 3 | Data3 |  | For this, will compare 2nd and 5th row date to calculate date for this field |
| 4 | Data4 |  | For this, will compare 3rd and 5th row to generate date |
| 5 | Data5 | 24/01/2021 08:00:30 | Exists |
| 6 | Data6 |  |  |
| 7 | Data7 |  |  |
| 8 | Data8 |  |  |

Is this proper or another solution?

Comment: If it is a one-time run, I suggest you run a query against your database directly without involving your Laravel program

Comment: Run a simply query just one time `$data =  \DB::table('table_name')->where('created_at', NULL)->update(['created_at', '01/02/2021 08:00:30']);`

Comment: Do you need a query or some kind of laravel based script? If its totally dependent on database side please tag your question with the database like sql-server or mysql etc

Comment: unfortunately created_at equals the real creation of the DB row. With simple sql UPDATE WHERE IS NULL you can set some date but I am not sure if this will be helpful for using that field for any kind of process. I saw that the difference from the example is exactly 3 days as between the dates, are those rows added once per day ?

Comment: @sta this static query will save only one date so ordering by date won't work